# Memory Leaking after reading CGImage data

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

I'm trying to understand why every time I call the following block of code in my level loading routing, it leaks memory according to XCode's 5.0.1 memory monitor. This block of code is meant to check the actual bounds of the image according to their alpha chanel.

```
        UIImageView* iv = (UIImageView*)m_image->GetId();

        // First get the image into your data buffer
        CGImageRef image = [iv.image CGImage];
        int width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
        int height = CGImageGetHeight(image);
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        void* rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);
        int bytesPerPixel = 4;
        int bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
        int bitsPerComponent = 8;
        CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

       CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), image);
       CGContextRelease(context);

       // rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.
       int lx=99999999,bx=0,ly=99999999,by=0;
       for( int x=0; x<width; x++ )
       {
           for( int y=0; y<height; y++ )
           {
                int pixelInfo = (bytesPerRow * y) + x * bytesPerPixel; // data is a png
                unsigned char* d = (unsigned char*)rawData;
                if( d[pixelInfo + 3] ) // check alpha
                {
                     if( x < lx ) lx = x;
                     if( x > bx ) bx = x;
                     if( y < ly ) ly = y;
                     if( y > by ) by = y;
                }
           }
       }
       free(rawData);
```

If you guys have a better approach to this problem then please advise, but this implementation works great appart form the fact that it leaks.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post this code m_image->GetId()

Comment: It may be unsigned char* d = (unsigned char*)rawData; and the pointer d may be the leak.

Comment: @Tony m_image is just a wrapper around UIImageView 

`id GetId() { return m_control; }`

unsigned char* d is just a pointer on the stack, I don't see potential leaking here.

Comment: I just tested: removing everything after `CGContextRelease`, except the final `free(rawData)`, still leaks.